# Heroku: site not showing

Tags: heroku, redux, mern, redux-devtools-extension

I have a website on Heroku that works normally when accessing from my computer, but when from another PC or any other device, it only shows a blank page.

Tried running `heroku logs -t` but it doesn't show any issues. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my poorly explained question, but I found the solution to this issue.
Since I'm working with the MERN Stack on this project, I was using the Redux DevTools Chrome Extension on both Opera and Chrome, and I was testing my site only on those browsers. When accessing from other browsers or devices that didn't have that extension, the site wouldn't load.

It happened because I was passing undefined (from browsers that didn't have the extension) to compose on my store.js, so I just had to comment that line:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    // window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    // commented the line above and it loaded normally
  )
);
```

I only use this extension for development, so there's no reason for deploying the final app with it. Hope this helps anyone who got this error :D